# How can I save a QGIS project with hyperlinks?

Tags: qgis, hyperlink

I have already created an hyperlink project using actions, it works, when I click on one point of my shapefile it opens a photo, but when I re-open the project, the action is gone and I have to create it again :( I tried to open the project from qgis and with double clicking direct on the project.

What can I do to mantain the action? Am I missing an step?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using and are you selecting the same layer for the action? I can confirm that this works for QGIS 2.8.2 64-but for Windows 7 =)

Comment: I´m using QGIS 2.8.2 and Windows 7, I only have one layer in my project a point shapefile, it only has 5 points, what could it be?

Comment: jajaja Good question, let me try !

Comment: I swear a had done it before! but I thought no because it is working now, you have the reason!!! jaja terrible mistake, sorry to waste your time!! Im very thankful! so many points for you!!! :D

Comment: Haha most welcome and don't worry, I forget to save things myself! I will post the comment as an answer for the convencience of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating actions, always try to remember to **save the project** after you have inserted the action. All actions are saved in the project file (.qgs).

Hope this helps!